# How to get object reference in testcomplete + js?

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I have **ODT.Class**  Actions with code

```
function SetValue(text){
HowToGetObject? .Keys(text + "[Enter]")
}
```

And **ODT.Data**.CustomerName element it has type of Actions class, so I can use  SetValue method
Also it has method GetObject, that allow me to get object:

```
function GetObject(){
return NameMapping.Sys.Orders.OrderForm.Group.Customer
}
```

The bellow code works with system SetText() method

```
ODT.Data.CustomerNameTextField.GetObject().SetText("Text")
```

I need somehow get object reference in my SetValue(text) method in order to do bellow

```
ODT.Data.CustomerNameTextField.GetObject().SetValue("Text")
```

I'm interested in system SetText(string) method? How does it work?

**Will be glad to have any help.
Thanks in advance, Denis**

Comment: seems like i need override SetText function with prototype?
any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to get the object right within the SetValue method:

```
function SetValue(text){
  This.GetObject().Keys(text + "[Enter]")
}
```

The standard SetText method can be applied to editors that can have a textual value and just puts the text to these editor programmatically.

BTW, as far as I know, the ODT functionality is going to be completely removed from TestComplete soon. See [Object-Driven Testing](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/70385/) for details. Here is a sample demonstrating how to use the OOP approach without the ODT feature:

```
function customClass(newObjName)
{
  this.objName = newObjName; 
}

customClass.prototype.getObject = function()
{
  return eval(this.objName);
}

customClass.prototype.setValue = function(text)
{
  this.getObject().Keys(text + "[Enter]");
}

function Test()
{
  var obj = new customClass('Sys.Process("notepad").Window("Notepad").Window("Edit")');
  obj.setValue("Test");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I have waiting for SetValue("text") popup, and then test is failed

Comment: Do you have project example for it?                                                       `// Define a custom class
function customClass() 
{

  // Define a class property
  var classProperty;
}

// Define a class routine
customClass.prototype.classRoutine = function()
{
  // ...
}

function Test() 
{
  var obj;
  
  // Create an instance of the class
  obj = new customClass();
  
  // Set the class property
  obj.classProperty = 41;
  
  // Call the class routine
  obj.classRoutine();
}`

Comment: I've put a sample code that does not require ODT to the answer.

Comment: Sample, how to use the OOP approach without the ODT feature works fine in one file, but then I'm trying to use it in separate Tests it doesn't work. 
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance, 
Denis

Comment: This should work fine with several units as well. Put the class code to a unit (say `MyClassUnit`) and include this unit to your test unit with the `//USEUNIT MyClassUnit` statement.Then, you will be able to use the Test routine from my example in the second unit without any changes.